# I get an Exclusive Open failure when running code provided by Gord Thompson

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to use Gord's code to open and update a database.  I have modified the database path to my location.  The database to be updated is closed and no other users.  Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.  This is what I have:

```
Sub UpdatePublicDatabase()
Dim con As Object
Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
On Error GoTo UpdatePublicDatabase_OpenError
con.Open _
        "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" & _
        "Dbq=C:\Users\wfejr\Desktop\Sean's Program Files\Access Sales Tax Database.accdb;" & _
        "Exclusive=1;" & _
        "Uid=admin;" & _
        "Pwd=;"
On Error GoTo 0
con.Execute "DELETE FROM UpdateInfo"
con.Execute "INSERT INTO UpdateInfo SELECT * FROM [MS Access;DATABASE=" & Updater.accdb & ";].[UpdateInfo]"
con.Close
Debug.Print "Done."
Exit Sub

UpdatePublicDatabase_OpenError:
Debug.Print "Exclusive 'Open' failed. Quitting."
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Change the `Debug.Print` line to `debug.print err.description` to ensure the error is what you think it is.

Comment: Also, Gord Thompson has written **a lot** of code on Stack Overflow. It might be helpful if you add the link to the answer you are referring to.